# Express - Save not being called

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

He there,

I just started using express / mongoose and I'm new with the concept. Currently trying to update a counter each time a user logges in. I'm using expres 4.8.8, mongoose, 3.8.15, passport 0.2.1

I have the following route, the function is being called on success:

```
// Set up the 'signin' routes 
app.route('/signin')
   .get(users.renderSignin)
   .post(passport.authenticate('local', {
        failureRedirect: '/',
        failureFlash: true
   }),function(req,res,next){
        users.updateLoginCount(req.user.id);
        res.redirect('/');
    });
```

Then in the user controller, I want to update the login counter of the user that is currently logging in:

```
exports.updateLoginCount = function(user_id){
    User.findById(user_id, function(err,user){
        if(!err){
            user.counters.login += 1;
            user.save(function(err){
                console.log('start save');
                if(err) {
                    console.log(err);
                }else{
                    console.log(user.username + ' logged in for the ' + user.counters.login + ' time');
                }
            });
        }else{
            console.log('Error');
        }
    });
};
```

Model looks something like:

```
// Define a new 'UserSchema'
var UserSchema = new Schema({
    firstName: String,
    lastName: String,
    email: {
        type: String,
        // Validate the email format
        match: [/.+\@.+\..+/, "Please fill a valid email address"]
    },
    username: {
        type: String,
        // Set a unique 'username' index
        unique: true,
        // Validate 'username' value existance
        required: 'Username is required',
        // Trim the 'username' field
        trim: true
    },
    password: {
        type: String,
        // Validate the 'password' value length
        validate: [

            function(password) {
                return password && password.length > 6;
            }, 'Password should be longer'
        ]
    },
    salt: {
        type: String
    },
    provider: {
        type: String,
        // Validate 'provider' value existance
        required: 'Provider is required'
    },
    providerId: String,
    providerData: {},
    created: {
        type: Date,
        // Create a default 'created' value
        default: Date.now
    },

    counters:{
        login:{
            type:Number,
            default: 0,
        }   
    }

});
```

But somehow it doesn't call the user.save(). It also doesn't show any errors, so I have no idea what I'm doing wrong here. It works fine till the user.save() part.

I hope that someone can point out the mistake I'm making. If there is more information needed, please let me know!

Comment: Can you show how you're requiring your modules

Comment: Also I don't think exports. Is proper syntax though I could be wrong. It should me module.exports

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the node.js is asynchronus I believe that your res.redirect executed before the login update function finishes executing. So, you need to set a callback for your method and run the res.redirect after your update is completed.

You can use mongoose update statement to increase a value like below by the way. Of course go on with the findById if you need other user info.

```
    exports.updateLoginCount = function(user_id, callback){
        User.update('_id' : user_id, {$inc: {"counters.login" : 1}}, function(err){
            if(err)
               console.log(err);
            else{
                  console.log(user_id + " login count increased by one" );
                  callback();
            }
        });
    }
```

Calling the method;

```
...
}),function(req,res,next){
        users.updateLoginCount(req.user.id, function(){
             res.redirect('/');
        });
    });
```

PS: I don't have a chance to test it now though, probably includes some syntax errors :)